# Button not working asynchronously (8051 code)

Tags: asynchronous, microcontroller, interrupt, interrupt-handling, 8051

This is the code I currently have that is supposed to detect when a button is pressed. If I create functions such as the firstmenu function where I call the synchronous button function (getkeysync), then the program works and the correct key is returned. However, if I tried the asynchronous route, (via getakey) and followed this example and ran it by pressing the "right" button about 100ms after the program started, then regardless of how much I hold it down, the options for the second menu are skipped and menuthree function is then executed.

I understand menuone, menutwo, menuthree, menufour, and menufive functions aren't implemented yet, but that isn't my issue.

Is there a way I can solve this issue asynchronously? By that I mean, I want to use getakey function more often in my menus and after the user makes his choice, I don't want to put the CPU to a forced endless loop until the key is released.

In fact, I want to be able to process other functions (which I'll create later) while it's the user's turn to make a choice.

```
KCENTER equ 3 ;this value is returned if both left and right keys are pressed at once.
KLEFT equ 2 ;left key pressed value
KRIGHT equ 1 ;right key pressed value
KCENTERH equ 7 ;both left and right keys held down

 mov TL1,#0h ;reset timer reload values
 mov TH1,#0h
 mov TMOD,#22h  ;Timer=0-255
 mov SP,#055h   ;set stack
 setb ET1 ;enable timer interrupt
 setb EA  ;enable all interrupts
 clr TF1 ;clear overflow flag
 setb TR1 ;start timer


firstmenu:
  lcall printfirstmenu ;function (not shown) to display first menu
  lcall getfkey ;stall until key is pressed
  cjne R6,#KCENTER,centerb
  ljmp menufour ;go to menufour if center is pressed
  centerb:
  cjne R6,#KLEFT,leftb
  ljmp menufive ;go to menufive if left is pressed
  leftb:
  cjne R6,#KRIGHT,rightb
  ljmp somemenu ;go to somemenu if right is pressed (this works)
  rightb:


somemenu:
  clr KEYDET ;clear detection
  lcall printamenu ;function (not shown) to display a menu
  menu2:
lcall getakey ;try to get key without stalling. Return 0 if no key.
cjne R6,#KCENTERH,nohold
  ;center key held down
  subb A,#33h ;compare hold time to time it takes to execute 51 interrupts
  jc timelow ;if time is high enough...
  ljmp othermenu ;then go to previous menu
  timelow:
  clr C ;clear carry. If center hold doesn't work, then no other key counts.
nohold:
jnc menu2 ;if no static key is pressed, jump back.
cjne R6,#KCENTER,centerk
  ljmp menuone ;go to menuone if center is pressed
centerk:
cjne R6,#KLEFT,leftk
  ljmp menutwo ;go to menutwo if center is pressed
leftk:
cjne R6,#KRIGHT,rightk
  ljmp menuthree ;go to menuthree if right is pressed (but this always executes without waiting for user input!)
rightk:
  ljmp menu2



InterruptHandler:
  clr EA    ;turn interrupts off
  clr TR1   ;turn timer off
  clr TF1   ;clear timer overflow
  push ACC  ;save A
  push PSW  ;save PSW
  lcall prockey ;run key function
  mov TL1,#0h   ;reset reload counters
  mov TH1,#0h
  pop PSW   ;restore PSW
  pop ACC   ;restore A
  setb EA   ;turn interrupts on
  setb TR1  ;turn timer on
reti    ;exit interrupt

;function getkeysync forces stall until key is returned.
;all key values are stored in R6.

getkeysync:
  clr KEYDET
  getkeysync2:
lcall getakey
  jnc getkeysync2
ret

;Get values and return immediately (async function)
getakey:
  mov R6,GOTKEY
  mov C,KEYDET
  mov A,KEYMD
ret

;process key interrupt
;LKEY and RKEY are independant hardware keys with inverted values.
;values: 0=pressed, 1=not pressed
;the KEYS variable stores bit information of captured keys

prockey:
  mov C,LKEY
  cpl C
  mov KEYS.1,C ;2nd LSB of KEYS is LKEY true value
  mov C,RKEY
  cpl C
  mov KEYS.0,C ;LSB of KEYS is RKEY true value
  mov A,KEYS
  anl A,#3h ;Possible values for A: 0=nothing pressed, 1=Right, 2=left, 3=both.
  jz gotnokey
;key detected as pressed.
clr KEYDET
mov KEYTEMP,#0h
inc KEYHOLD ;increment hold counter once per interrupt call
mov A,KEYHOLD ;if counter goes past 255 then assume key press is valid.
jnz keyend
  ;here, the key is alwats held down for 255 interrupt calls 255 times
  ;and can safely assume the user hit the key (and not debounce)
  setb KEYS.2 ;set flag
  mov KEYHOLD,#0FFh ;set to FF so this section executes continuously until key is let go.
  mov KEYTEMP,KEYS ;copy key value with flag to a temporary variable
  inc KEYMD
  mov A,KEYMD ;increase mega delay counter (keymd) to detect long key presses
  jnz keyend
  mov KEYMD,#0FFh
  ljmp keyend
  gotnokey:
;here the system thinks key wasn't pressed
mov KEYMD,#0h ;reset extended counter
dec KEYHOLD ;lower short key hold counter
mov A,KEYHOLD
inc A
jnz keyend
  ;once hold counter is below zero, reset to zero and detect key
  mov KEYHOLD,#0h
  jnb KEYTEMP.2,keyend
    ;here, keypress is valid
    clr KEYTEMP.2 ;so invalidate the bit
    clr KEYS.2    ;in both variables
    setb KEYDET   ;and set key detection flag
  keyend:
  ;this gets executed at the end of prockey
  mov A,KEYTEMP ;get saved key
  anl A,#7h ;only accept lower 3 bits
  mov GOTKEY,A  ;and set output key variable to it
  jnb KEYDET,noreskey
mov KEYTEMP,#0h ;clear temporary key if key is detected
  noreskey:
ret
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle multiple actions from different sources you could use a state machine. A variable defines the state. 0 could be the initial state. Menu level 1 could be 1000, 2000 etc, submenu 1100. Each time the handler is called the handler should return as soon as possible. If processing takes more time, use a timer and interrupt to subdivide processing yime or use multiple states.

The main loop calls a button and/or sensor handler, and the menu handler. When the user chooses a menu, the state changes so when menu is called again it knows what to do, an action and/or change state again.

This way it's much easier to keep track of when what happens and keep user interaction asynchronous, and respond quickly.

Comment: +1 for thinking of a way to minimize code size. I'm going to try to put the button handler in the main routine instead of an interrupt and see what happens.